# Screeps repairer code only fix a few pieces of wall

Tags: repair, screeps

The problem mainly is the repairer will only fix a few pieces of wall, like one or two pieces. So, it don't make it work. If you have better ideas to add to the code or to fix it.
Please write in the comment or answer what tou fix or add. Thank you very much. (My first time play Screeps and use stack**overflow**

This my code:

```
var roleRepairer = {

run: function(creep)
{
    if(creep.memory.repairing && creep.store[RESOURCE_ENERGY] == 0) {
            creep.memory.repairing = false;
            creep.say(' harvest');
        }
        if(!creep.memory.repairing && creep.store.getFreeCapacity() == 0) {
            creep.memory.repairing= true;
            creep.say(' repair');
        }

    if(!creep.memory.repairing && creep.carry.energy == creep.carryCapacity)
    {
        creep.say('repairing');
        creep.memory.repairing = true;
        
    }
    if(creep.memory.repairing)
    {
        var potentialRepairSite = creep.room.find(FIND_STRUCTURES, {filter: (structure) => {return (structure.structureType == STRUCTURE_ROAD || structure.structureType == STRUCTURE_RAMPART || structure.structureType == STRUCTURE_WALL)}});    
        
        for(i = 0; i < potentialRepairSite.length; i++)
        {
            if(creep.repair(potentialRepairSite[i]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE)
            {
                creep.moveTo(potentialRepairSite[i], {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffaa00'}});
            }
        }
            
    }
    else
    {
        var sources = creep.room.find(FIND_SOURCES);
            if(creep.harvest(sources[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
                creep.moveTo(sources[0], {visualizePathStyle: {stroke: '#ffaa00'}});
        }
            
        
        
    }
    
}
};

module.exports = roleRepairer;
```

Please help me fix it out, thank you.

Comment: The screeps only fix two pieces of wall.

Comment: It looks like there's some logic issues with your memory. You've got it setting to true whenever you're not repairing. That really needs to be an if-else statement rather than an if-if statement. The second one always gets hit if the first gets hit, meaning you repair 2x.